# How to add web project module in existing java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, webproject

I have existing Java project and want to add web module to it. Is there any way to add dynamic web project as a module in a Java project using Eclipse?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion.But I can add "Project Facets" to Java EE project. I want to add web module to Java project not Java EE project. Eclipse suggests me to convert project to faceted form to add facet. Will that work ?

Comment: very easy solution switch to intelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You need to go to your project settings, find "Project Facets" on the left. Then you can check "Dynamic Web Project" checkbox. Make sure to set up the facet before you hit "Apply" because it will be hard to do later on. There will be "additional configuration" button somewhere once you check the facet.

Adding the web functionality to existing project has always been buggy though. Try it and if it doesn't work then you'd have to create a new project and copy your stuff over.

More detailed info is here: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fcfacets.html