# How to add Web module in STS 4?

Tags: java, tcserver, pivotal-tc

I have projects which has a war file in it, but unable to add web modules in it.
I have installed the plugin in my STS 4, plugin name - Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.13.
I have refered the below question 
[How to add web project module in existing java project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763978/how-to-add-web-project-module-in-existing-java-project-in-eclipse) added the project facet but still not able too add Web Module, below is the screenshot.

[image]

Can anyone please help on what I missed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add other modules by right clicking the project and go to "Spring" and then "Edit Starters". Bingo.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkQVG.jpg)